# What's the difference between "auto x = vector<int>()" and "vector<int> x"?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, stdvector

What is the difference between:

```
auto x = vector<int>();
```

and

```
vector<int> x;
```

Are both of these declarations equivalent, or is there some difference with the run-time complexity?

Comment: The first results in a call to a default constructor and a call to a move constructor. The second results in a call to a default constructor. Even if the compiler optimizes both to result in the same assembly, the second one is the one to go for readability.

Comment: Note that they are not the same for all classes. E.g. `std::array<int,10>`. The first will initialize to all 0, the second may not.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

They have the same effect since C++17. Both construct an object named `x` with type `std::vector<int>`, which is initialized by the default constructor of `std::vector`.

Precisely the 1st one is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), `x` is copy-initialized from a [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) temporary. From C++17 this kind of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is guaranteed, as the result `x` is initialized by the default constructor of `std::vector` directly. Before C++17, copy elision is an optimization:

> even when it takes place and the copy/move (since C++11) constructor is not called, it still must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed:

The 2nd one is [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), as a class type `x` is initialized by the default constructor of `std::vector`.

Note that the behaviors might be different for other types, depending on the type's behavior and `x`'s storage duration.

Comment: @HTNW Pretty sure it's still copy-initialization. The term is defined in terms of [syntax](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#15), not semantics.